# Standard Form of a Line

Tags: output-formatting

When finding the line between two points, I've been using `InterpolatingPolynomial` (which I know is probably overkill). I get an answer like the following:

> `Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{4, -6}, {10, -7}}, x]]`
>
> -(44/7) + x/14

I would like this to be reformatted into [standard form of a line](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardForm.html), e.g. as the expression `x-14y-88`.

In particular, my initial points are always integer pairs, so the output needed is `Ax+By+C` where `A`, `B`, and `C` are integers, (`A` and `B` relatively prime).

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

(Yes, I could do the math to figure out `A`, `B`, and `C` explicitly, but the heart of my question is wondering if Mathematica has a built in way to convert its default explicit answers into an implicit format.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example using your code (which do not work for lines parallel with `y` axis):

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}}, x] - y /. x1 -> 1 /. 
 y1 -> 2 /. x2 -> 3 /. y2 -> 5 // FactorTermsList // Last

(* 1 + 3 x - 2 y *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
eq=Expand[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{4, -6}, {10, -7}}, x]];
(LCM@@Denominator[List@@eq])(eq-y)//Expand
```